# Scala - List to List of tuples

Tags: scala

Beginner here.

Sorry but I did'nt found an answer so I ask the question here.

I want to know how to do this by using the `Scala API` :

`(blabla))( -> List(('(',2),(')',2))`

Currently I have this :

```
"(blabla))(".toCharArray.toList.filter(p => (p == '(' || p == ')')).sortBy(x => x)
```

Output :

```
List((, (, ), ))
```

Now how can I map each character to the tuples I describe ?

Example for a general case :

```
"t:e:s:t" -> List(('t',2),('e',1),('s',1),(':',3))
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to count number of opening and closing parentheses in source string and yield result as a list of 2 tuples?

Comment: @arkonautom Not only for parenthesis. I have added an example of what I'm trying to achieve using the Scala API but without success for the moment.

Comment: you want the character and the count of their occurrences in a string in a tupple omitting multiple output of characters , right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val source = "ok:ok:k::"
val chars = source.toList
val shorter = chars.distinct.map( c => (c, chars.count(_ == c)))    
//> shorter  : List[(Char, Int)] = List((o,2), (k,3), (:,4))
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use pattern matching and another functions. Is it possible only using the Scala API ?

Comment: Removed "long and ugly" and left "short and fancy" version.

Answer (score 4):

Classic `groupBy . mapValues` use case:

```
scala> val str = "ok:ok:k::"
str: String = ok:ok:k::

scala> str.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size) // identity <=> (x => x)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(k -> 3, : -> 4, o -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like sschaef's solution very much, but I was wondering if anyone could weigh in on how efficient that solution is compared to this one:

```
scala> val str = "ok:ok:k::"
str: String = ok:ok:k::

scala> str.foldLeft(Map[Char,Int]().withDefaultValue(0))((current, c) => current.updated(c, current(c) + 1)) 
res29: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(o -> 2, k -> 3, : -> 4)
```

I think my solution is slower.  If we have n total occurrences and m unique values:

**My solution:** we have the fold left over all occurrences or n.  For each of these occurrences we look up once to find the current count and then again to create the updated the map. I'm assuming that the creating of the updated map is constant time.
Total complexity: n * 2m or O(n*m)

**sschaef's solution:** we have the groupBy which I'm assuming just adds entries onto a list without checking the map (so for all values this would be a constant time look up plus appending to the list) so n.  Then for the mapValues it probably iterates over the unique values and grabs the size for each key's list. I'm assuming that getting the size of each entry's list is constant time.
Total complexity: O(n + m)

Does this seem correct or am I mistaken in my assumptions?